# How to check if google.navigation intent/url scheme is supported from within a web app?

Tags: javascript, android, navigation, android-intent

I would like to know, using javascript, if something like this:

```
location = "google.navigation:q="+myDestAddress;
```

is supported before actually invoking it, and if it is not revert to the plain old google maps url:

```
location = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+myStartAddress+"&daddr="+myDestAddress;
```

Note: I already check that the device is an android one using the user agent, but that is not enough as, as far as I know, the "google.navigation" intent is only supported in the US and only on some devices/OS versions.

Thanks!

Comment: For starters, you could check the user agent to make sure that it's Android. Don't know about introspecting the system to see what's supported though :(

Comment: Thanks, I did not mention that but I already check the user agent to see if it's an android device. That is the easy part :)

Comment: @Sergio - Too bad this is a good question

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for:

```
if(typeof google == "undefined" || typeof google.navigation == "undefined") {
    location = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+myStartAddress+"&daddr="+myDestAddress;
else {
    location = "google.navigation:q="+myDestAddress;
}
```

Comment: Mmm, I don't think the google namespace is available unless you load some of their libraries. And even after you do that, I'm not sure having google.navigation defined means that the google.navigation intent is available (they are two different things). Anyhow, do you have a link for your sources so that I can check it out?